# How to add tiles in Visual Studio Web application using DevExpress

Tags: asp.net, web-applications, visual-studio-2012, devexpress, tiles

I added and used [Tile Control](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_SsRalcL_58) in windows application (WinForms). But i am unable to use tiles in any of the web applications on Visual Studio. Besides using metro css, is there any method to use DevExpress tile control in Visual Studio web applications? Please Help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**From**: [Mehul Harry's DevExpress Blog Article](http://community.devexpress.com/blogs/aspnet/archive/2012/12/11/q-amp-a-from-dxtreme-creating-ios-apps-webinar.aspx)

> Any way to generate a "Tile" feel for Websites using DXTREME...
>   ????????

**Answer**: For websites, you can try the [TileView widget](http://help.devexpress.com/HTML/#!UI%20Widgets/TileView).  For Window, `DXTREME XAML` as it contains a `Windows 8 Tile control`.

> ***Is there any method to use DevExpress tile control in Visual Studio web applications?***
>
> There is not such control for ASP.NET WebForms. At the same time I
>   believe that the same behavior can be implemented using
>   [ASPxDocking](http://demos.devexpress.com/aspxperiencedemos/Docking/Widgets.aspx). Please refer to our demos starting from this -
>   [Docking - Forbidden Zones](http://demos.devexpress.com/ASPxperienceDemos/Docking/ForbiddenZones.aspx). You can test any demo using a mobile
>   tablet device. You can enable any existing theme on a corresponding
>   tab on a demo page.

Hope this helps..

Comment: Thanks for links, i would also like to add i created tiles in silver-light web application. Is there any major drawback in using Silverlight instead of normal asp.net websites?